# What is the reason of changing one value in a list affects the value of a cell of a data frame inside a method?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

The below code is the problematic code where after executing Line-coalition1.remove(preferedP) the value of df_PoS[1][0] changes. The thing is I checked the reference(memory) value both of the variables and it was different. Please help if you could.

```py
def merge(lstOffloatingP,possibleCoalitionSetSplit,df_distanceNear,df_PoS):

    tmpCoalitionSetMerge=possibleCoalitionSetSplit.copy()
    tmpCoalitionSetMerge1=possibleCoalitionSetSplit.copy()


    updateAllMergeSet=[]
    
    for coalition in possibleCoalitionSetSplit:
        print('coalition',coalition) 
        coalitionCopy = coalition.copy()
        
        for p in coalition:
            
            preferedP=df_distanceNear[p].idxmin() 
            
            if p not in lstOffloatingP:
                
                if preferedP not in coalition:

                    for coalition1 in tmpCoalitionSetMerge1:

                        if preferedP in coalition1:

                            coalition1.remove(preferedP)

                            updateAllMergeSet.append(coalition1)

                            coalition.append(preferedP) 

                            updateAllMergeSet.append(coalition)
                            print('updateAllMergeSet1',updateAllMergeSet)

            else:
        
                updateAllMergeSet.append([p])

                
          
    return updateAllMergeSet, df_PoS
```

Result:

Before and after calling function the value and memory of both the variable are,

```
df_PoS[1][0] =[[3], [0], [1], [4], [2], [8], [5], [6], [9, 7]]

df_PoS[1][0] ID MEMORY = 0x1a64bb5cac8

possibleCoalitionSetSplit =[[3], [0], [1], [4], [2], [8], [5], [6], [9, 7]]

possibleCoalitionSetSplit MEMORY = 0x1a64b87c088
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to the shallow copy. A deep copy of the first two lines of the function as below would solve this problem,

```
tmpCoalitionSetMerge=copy.deepcopy(possibleCoalitionSetSplit) 
tmpCoalitionSetMerge1=copy.deepcopy(possibleCoalitionSetSplit)
```